# (Angular 7) Prevent some modules (authorized) to be prerendered and keep the default angular behavior

Tags: angular, typescript, module, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have some modules that just authorized users can access and there is no need to be `prerendered` because I just use `SSR` for `SEO`.

I am having some issues on how to render that modules because the node server is unauthorized and because of `TransferHttpCacheModule` the browser is not doing the apis calls again.

I am using the latest version of Angular, using Lazy Modules and followed the Universal tutorial on the official website.

Can someone help me how to figure it out and fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I just figure it out, as my application have an `HttpInterceptor` and for `TransferHttpCacheModule` work, we need to import it along with `HttpClientModule` on `app.module.ts`, but I forget to move the `HttpInterceptor` from the inner module to outside, so that's why the authorized calls weren't working.

At the end, it wasn't related to Angular Universal, but just a rookie mistake from myself.

Hope it can help someone oneday ;)